# Cannot Create Admin Login on CouchDB

Tags: linux, couchdb

I have a fresh install of CouchDB on a new server. I set it up on a dev server and upon starting the service and accessing the web interface I was able to click the fix it button and create an admin login. On the new server using the exact same steps and software when clicking fix it and entering the new username and password it just spins and keeps thinking and does nothing else. If I refresh the screen it just starts over with no visible change. Anyone know where to look to see what the issue is or know why this is happening. I am fairly new to CouchDB.

Note: I am using the Fix link in the lower right side menu to create the login, it worked before on another server

I followed this article, see section on creating admin using Fix It

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-couchdb-and-futon-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Could you inspect the network traffic, when you click on "Fix this"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the admin with curl. If curl isn't installed on your machine, install it with this simple command:
`apt-get update && apt-get install curl`

then execute the following curl command:
`$1: Username`
`$2: Userpassword`
`curl -X PUT $HOST/_config/admins/$1 -d '"'$2'"'`

Source for further information about that topic: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/intro/security.html